# How to export libraries in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

When trying to export socket.io this way `import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';` getting error `TS1192: Module '"***/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/index"' has no default export`.

My tsconfig.client.json file has the following settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./public/js/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib":[
      "es2015", "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/client/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to import a single property?

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
import { connect } from 'socket.io-client';
```